# Apache NetBeans IDE 18 run project button not functioning

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to run a file but not matter what I do, I can not even run it. I've tried creating new files and adding content there, but no luck. Is there something wrong with my Netbeans? This is what it looks like:

[The Run Project button is greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcoFb.png)

I tried searching online for an answer, but I could find nothing. I tried restarting the program, but no such luck.

Comment: You need to provide far more information, and as it stands your question cannot be answered. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for general guidelines on improving your question. The biggest single improvement to your question would be to fully detail the steps someone else would have to follow to attempt to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "Run" button is for running the main project (you can define a project as the main one by right-clicking it in the projects tab and selecting "Set as Main Project" from the popup menu).

To run a file, select one of these options:

1. Go to the Run menu, and select "Run File"; or
2. Right click the file in the project pane, and select "run file" from the popup menu.

Note that the file has to be runnable (i.e. have a class that has a `public static void main(String args[])` method defined).